# How to avoid the blink effect when validating with simple validator and asyncValidator?

Tags: angularjs, validation, asynchronous

I have the following input:

```
<input id="firstname" class="form-control"
   name="firstname" ng-model="event.firstname" autocomplete="off"
   required validation-event-firstname ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { default: 300, blur: 0 } }">
```

`validation-event-firstname` is a custom async validator which call a rester server. I need the field to be `required`.

Here is the code to display the errors:

```
<ng-messages for="form.firstname.$error" role="alert" ng-show="(form.firstname.$dirty || form.firstname.$touched) && form.firstname.$invalid">
    <ng-message when="required" class="error-message">required</ng-message>
    <ng-message when="my-custom-validation" class="error-message">my custom validation</ng-message>
</ng-messages>
```

The problem is: when I refresh the page and put some content in the field, the error message "required" is shown something like 0.1s. This behaviour does not depend on the content of the field: if I put an invalid server value (triggered by `my-custom-validation`) or not, I can see the error message (and it disappears after 0.1s).

When I remove the directive `validation-event-firstname`, there is no problem. I think this issue does not depend on the code of the async validator, because I tried with my business code and with a simple `$timeout`, the effect is still the same.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/rF3H3hzE9iBxDmRYpzGc?p=preview problem is not reproduced, consider adding some code

Comment: Thank you for your lead you made me looking elsewhere. I cannot understand what is my problem: I removed ngAnimate dependency from my module (which was not necessary) and my issue is gone. I didn't succeed to reproduce with plunker event with ngAnimate...